# Error invoking Information on functions containing Legended

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling, error-trapping

**Bug fixed in version 11**

In adapting some plotting functions to utilize the `PlotLegends` option of version 9, I came across the following errors:

```
f[x_] := Legended[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, Pi}], x]
f[1];
Information[f]
```

> `TextForm[First::first: StandardForm[Short[Shallow[HoldForm[{}], {10, 50}], 5]] has a length of zero and no first element. >>]`

This is just a toy example for a more complex situation where I can't directly use the `PlotLegends` option but have to use `Legended` explicitly.

What is the best way to catch this error when a user invokes the above or types `?f` to see the code for this function. It seems the output of `Definition` works as expected (it formats the `Legended` contents, and that happens for other constructs such as `Framed` too).

Comment: For the error in `?f`, specifying `usage` message is enough `f::usage = "bla";`.

Comment: Wierd.. I can reproduce the problem at first time. But after doing some tracing, I quit the kernel, then the problem is gone! I restarted the whole mma, still [no problem now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mJZtR.jpg)!

Comment: @Silvia Yeah, me too! Weird indeed...

Comment: @Silvia The problem appears again if I evaluate plot somewhere else. And then even `f[x_]:=Legended[1,x]` produces this error.

Comment: Mmm not sure whether this one needs to be reported as a bug or exorcized

Comment: @swish Guess evaluating `f` introduced something to box functions. Check this: ``System`Dump`makeusageboxes[f[x_] := Legended["123", x]]``.

Comment: @Silvia Interesting observation. I have to add that to my question: the function should first be evaluated to see the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I `Trace`-ed the `Information[ f ]` command both before and after an invocation of `f` (with a simpler definition `f[x_] := Legended["123", x]`). By comparing the results, I found a function `` System`Dump`makeusageboxes ``:

[image: trace comparison]

which reduces to another function `` BoxForm`MakeBoxesWithTextFormatting ``:

> ```
> Attributes[BoxForm`MakeBoxesWithTextFormatting] = {HoldAllComplete}
>
> BoxForm`MakeBoxesWithTextFormatting[BoxForm`args___] := 
>           Block[Evaluate[BoxForm`$TextFormattingForms], 
>                 Block[{BoxForm`UseTextFormattingQ = True}, MakeBoxes[BoxForm`args]]]
> ```

By setting `` BoxForm`UseTextFormattingQ `` to `False` (which is its default global value), the problem seems to be bypassed:

```
Unprotect[BoxForm`MakeBoxesWithTextFormatting]

BoxForm`MakeBoxesWithTextFormatting[BoxForm`args___] := 
 Block[Evaluate[BoxForm`$TextFormattingForms], MakeBoxes[BoxForm`args]]

Protect[BoxForm`MakeBoxesWithTextFormatting]
```

---

[image: correct result]

## Edit

As it might be safer not to modify system functions, here is another possible workaround (the disadvantage is an extra `UpValue` item):

```
f /: Information[f, opt_] := 
 Block[{Internal`ConvertFormTest = (InputForm &)}, Information[f, opt]] /; 
  Internal`ConvertFormTest[] === None

Information[f]
```

I don't know why, but somehow `` Internal`ConvertFormTest[] `` is called after an invocation of `f`. Playing around it reveals its connection to some box formatting.

---

[image: trace comparison 2]

Comment: Unfortunately, your edited solution doesn't work with my original function. And your first solution (using `Unprotect`) still doesn't work with the function I defined in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24701/245) which motivated my question. But certainly some kind of `UpValues` solution will be the way to go, even if it has to be more hand-tuned... so I upvoted this. I'll wait a little more before accepting it.

Comment: @Jens Hmm.. More and more looks like a bug, I guess? Will try digging deeper tomorrow..

Comment: I agree it behaves like a bug. Would you mind adding the bug tag to the question (so I don't get in trouble for doing it myself)?

Comment: @Jens Of course not. Done.